# Log viewer with IntelliJ integration

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, log-viewer

I'm looking for a log viewer, the most interesting feature for me is integration with IntelliJ and opening log from remote servers. It can be IntelliJ plugin or standalone application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/). This is a standalone application with IntelliJ integration. You can click on stacktrace fragment and IntelliJ will open selected class at pointed line. See screenshot below:
[image: JumpToCode]

If you hover a mouse on stacktrace, code fragment will display as a tooltip:

[image: Tooltip]

You can check video with integration on youtube: [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbOFF56_7-A?hd=1)

You can open logs from remote server using SFTP, FTP, SMB or HTTP(S). It's really usefull if your application is deployed on tomcat in data center and you tail logs live with ability to open class from stacktrace in IntelliJ or view code fragment in OtrosLogViewer.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of OtrosLogViewer

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for `Log4JPlugin`

Jetbrains repository contains this plugin and way to configure this. look [here](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13?pr=idea) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Vigilog intellij plugin that does what you need
http://vigilog.sourceforge.net/jumptocode.html

Comment: This feature in OtrosLogViewer was insired by Vigilog. IntelliJ plugin was based on plugin used by Vigililog with some enchancment.